# LINQ finding the highest frequency

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to find the "most popular" game based on the number of occurrences.
So I wrote a linq query as below

```
 var query = (from evt in events
                        from game in evt.EventGames
                        group game by game.GameTypeId
                        into g
                        select new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()}).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).FirstOrDefault();

 var gameType = repository.GetRepository<GameType>().Find(query?.Key);
```

I realised that I am querying twice to get the game type which has the highest frequency.

Is it possible to get the game type from the first query itself?

-Alan-

Comment: Yes, just group by the `GameType` instead of the `GameTypeId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just group by the `GameType` instead of the `GameTypeId`.

```
var gameType = (from evt in events
                from game in evt.EventGames
                group game by game.GameType into g
                orderby g.Count() descending
                select g.Key)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: exactly what I want . Thanks. And var gameType = query, would do I guess without the key.

Comment: @AlanB Yes, I made a couple of edits and didn't fix that.  But now I have.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find all `GameTypes` which appear most often?

```
var gameTypeGroups =  from evt in events
                      from game in evt.EventGames
                      group game by game.GameTypeId
                      into g
                      orderby g.Count() descending 
                      select repository.GetRepository<GameType>().Find(g.Key);
IEnumerable<GameType> maxCountGroup = gameTypeGroups.FirstOrDefault();
```